# How would I go about reading from a packaged file?

Tags: java, file, jar, package

I have a file that I packaged in my JAR file, but I can't figure out how I would read the text file and store it into a String variable.
Any ideas anyone?

Comment: *"Any ideas anyone?"* 1. Do the [Basic I/O lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) of the tutorial.  2. Show some effort before asking questions.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend

[java.lang.Class#getResource(java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)
or
[java.lang.Class#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

This approach would work for any jar file, even if it's not in your current project/library/classpath:

```
String myJarFilename ="C:\\path\\to\\myfile.jar";
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(myJarFilename);
JarEntry jarEntry = jarFile.getJarEntry("mytextfile.txt");

if (jarEntry != null)
{
    InputStream is = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
    // do normal stuff here to read string from inputstream

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    byte[] charArr = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (bytesRead = is.read(charArr, 0, 2048) > 0)
    {
        sb.append(charArr, 0, bytesRead);            
    }
    String fileContent = sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you (or someone) please briefly explain how to store the whole file into a string variable?

Comment: The embedded text file or the Jar File?

Comment: The embedded text file please

Comment: Ok I roughed up the code for reading the file from the InputStream. May not be 100% perfect but gives you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [URLClassLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to access resources in a JAR archive.